# System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection vs Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does anyone have insight why one would use SnowflakeDbConnection (https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/blob/master/Snowflake.Data/Client/SnowflakeDbConnection.cs) instead of OdbcConnection  other than the fact that you need ODBC driver installed on the machine? Are there other benefits to using the .net connector?

Comment: The .net connector is probably a bit less tested since it's one of the newer connectors, but if you have a preference for the framework, it's definitely another option for some folks.  Not sure if there's anything specific to answer or if you're seeing issues with one as opposed to another.

Comment: I have started using it. However, I am trying to understand if there are any specific features in this which are not in ODBCConnection?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there other benefits to using the .net connector?

Besides not requiring to install, setup, and configure ODBC libraries and data sources, the .NET connector allows your application to be cross-platform, able to run anywhere [.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core) is available (Linux, macOS, etc.) in a self-contained manner.